# What is the best/right way to add multiple handlers for same event with Kivy?

Tags: python, event-handling, kivy

I recently discovered the Kivy-Framework and I'm currently playing around with the [PongGame-Example](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html#connect-input-events).
I implemented some functions to make it possible to control the paddles with the keyboard by giving the paddle class some handlers that I can bind to the keyboard events.
Unfortunately I struggle a bit with kivy's event binding.

At first I tried the following in my PongGame class

```
self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.player1.on_keyboard_down)
self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.player1.on_keyboard_up)
self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.player2.on_keyboard_down)
self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.player2.on_keyboard_up)
```

In c# and WPF I was used to be able to bind multiple handlers to the same event and I think I saw something similar in Kivy's docs.
Unfortunately in Kivy this seems to have the effect that the previously added bindings are overwritten by the later, which results in only the second paddle being able to move.
In the docs I found that kivy prevents a function to be added as a handler more than once so I tried `fbind` instead because the docs say

> As opposed to bind(), it does not check that this function and largs/kwargs has not been bound before to this name. So binding the same callback multiple times will just keep adding it.

and I thought both methods are somehow seen as the same function. Unfortunately the result is the same.

So what I did instead is to create additional methods to group the handlers together and bind them instead.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.player1.set_input_keys('w', 's')
    self.player2.set_input_keys('up', 'down')
    self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)

    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_key_down)
    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self._on_key_up)

def _keyboard_closed(self):
    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_key_down)
    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self._on_key_up)
    self._keyboard = None

def _on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    self.player2.on_keyboard_down(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
    self.player1.on_keyboard_down(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)

def _on_key_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
    self.player1.on_keyboard_up(keyboard, keycode)
    self.player2.on_keyboard_up(keyboard, keycode)
```

Unfortunately this has the disadvantage that I cannot unbind individual handlers. For example when switching from two players to one.

I'm new to kivy and somehow geting the feeling that I'm putting the cart before the horse here.

What would be the right or the kivy way to handle this?

Complete code here https://pastebin.com/uq9pxHcF
the kv file is exactly the same as the example in the [tutorial (you may have to scroll down a bit)](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html#connect-input-events) except that I used `#:kivy 1.10.0`.

Comment: share the .kv.........

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry, the kv file is the same as in the tutorial. I didn't made any changes to the code in the kv file except for the version. updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. The Right Way**

You can process the keycodes in the `_on_keyboard_down` method.

```
class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    PLAYER1_UP = 'w'
    PLAYER1_DOWN = 's'
    PLAYER2_UP = 'up'
    PLAYER2_DOWN = 'down'
    SENSITIVITY = 10

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == self.PLAYER1_UP:
            self.move_player(self.player1, self.SENSITIVITY)
        elif keycode[1] == self.PLAYER1_DOWN:
            self.move_player(self.player1, -self.SENSITIVITY)
        if keycode[1] == self.PLAYER2_UP:
            self.move_player(self.player2, self.SENSITIVITY)
        elif keycode[1] == self.PLAYER2_DOWN:
            self.move_player(self.player2, -self.SENSITIVITY)
        return True

    def move_player(self, player, displacement):
        player.center_y += displacement

    # serve_ball and update methods, ref tutorial
    # ...
```

Notes

- To be able to play both sides with just one set of keys, we broke up the if-elif chain.
- Use `_keyboard_closed` to *un*bind the handler, ref the example from the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.Keyboard).

**2. Handler Handling**

You're right about that cart, you had it backwards. From the [Event Dispatcher](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html?highlight=opposed%20bind%20does%20check):

> If a callback has already been bound to a given event or property, it won’t be added again.

Saying that the ***same*** handler can't be added to the same event multiple times, with regular bind. What you really want is ***different*** methods to be called for the same event. As luck would have it, that's easy...

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
        self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down1)
    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down2)

def _keyboard_closed(self):
    self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down1)
    self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down2)
    self._keyboard = None

def _on_keyboard_down1(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if keycode[1] == self.PLAYER1_UP:
        self.move_player(self.player1, self.SENSITIVITY)
    elif keycode[1] == self.PLAYER1_DOWN:
        self.move_player(self.player1, -self.SENSITIVITY)
    return True

def _on_keyboard_down2(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if keycode[1] == self.PLAYER2_UP:
        self.move_player(self.player2, self.SENSITIVITY)
    elif keycode[1] == self.PLAYER2_DOWN:
        self.move_player(self.player2, -self.SENSITIVITY)
    return False
```

There's one gotcha, the last added handler should return `False` or it will mark the event as handled, and the first handler will never be called.

For a deeper understanding I advise having another look at kivy [properties](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html):

> The reason that both functions are called is simple. Binding doesn’t
>   mean overriding. Having both of these functions is redundant and you
>   should generally only use one of the methods of listening/reacting to
>   property changes.

Comment: My initial solution was similar to your first example but then it struck me that I should maybe implement the input handling in the paddle class, which I did then and that's what finally got me into trouble with the bindings. Is it inherently wrong to do it like I did? On first thought It kinda felt smarter, because I don't have to write additional handling code for additional players (paddles), although I already can think of additional drawbacks. For example when the paddle class gets replaced by something else later in the design process, the handling code would have to be written again.

Comment: @Takiro Tightly coupling the paddles to an input source allows little flexibility. You can achieve loose coupling by adding a layer of abstraction. This can be as simple as my `move_player` function. Entering the world of design patterns, the [bridge pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) and [mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) support loose coupling and are used a lot in game and GUI dev.

Comment: thanks for the additional info, didn't knew these patterns yet.